# How to detect if Android has full USB support or not?

Tags: android, usb, usb-otg

My application uses `UsbManager` to communicate with USB cameras. Some devices don't have USB support. These will return `null` for `(UsbManager)context.getSystemService( Context.USB_SERVICE )`, or they will throw a `NoSuchMethodError` exception when enumerating devices. I can detect both and display a message properly. Unfortunately, some Androids that don't detect USB devices cause neither of these problems. They just return an empty list of USB devices. How can I properly detect that this system doesn't support USB OTG?

Comment: Have you tried using `android.hardware.usb.host` with `<uses-feature>` or `PackageManager` and `hasSystemFeature()`?

Comment: @CommonsWare: `if (!context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.usb.host"))` works, thanks a lot! Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official way to determine if the device has USB host capability is to use the associated system feature.

Ideally, add a `<uses-feature>` element to your manifest, indicating that you are interested in the `android.hardware.usb.host` feature. If you do not absolutely need that feature, add `android:required="false"` as an attribute.

If you went with `android:required="false"`, and you want to determine whether the device is a USB host at runtime, use `PackageManager`, [`hasSystemFeature()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29), and [`FEATURE_USB_HOST`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_USB_HOST). `FEATURE_USB_HOST` is defined as the same string as you would be using in `<uses-feature>` (`android.hardware.usb.host`).

Comment: I have samsung galaxy s3 neo (http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9300i_galaxy_s3_neo-6289.php)
This phone does not support OTG, but FEATURE_USB_HOST returns true.

Comment: Some phones have the option to enable/disable OTG from settings. How can I know that status? The phone has the OTG support and it is disabled in Settings.

Comment: @ZachariasManuel: I am not aware of any documented and supported way to determine that. My guess is that this is something specific to that device manufacturer, and therefore it would be up to that device manufacturer to tell you if there is a way to detect the setting's state.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean getUsbConnection(Context context) {
        intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE"));
        return intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected");
    }
```